# Comparing Data from 2 tables SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Help i'm a newbie.  I am trying to extract data that may be in one table but isn't in the other table.

This returns multiple rows of the same information.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Schools, Schools_Current
WHERE ([Schools].[School_ID]<>[Schools_Current].[School_ID]);
```

Comment: I would suggest to use SQL Joins to do that http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM Schools_Current
WHERE School_ID NOT IN (
  SELECT School_ID
  FROM Schools
)
```

Comment: I tried this.  It asked me  to enter a parameter value.  I'm unsure what to enter.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with access, but it seems that there is a page to troubleshoot that [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/why-does-access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-HA010274377.aspx). This query isn't supposed to receive any parameters.